# Set CPU frequency scaling to wait one second before scaling down

Tags: kubuntu, cpu, scaling

I notice that my Kubuntu 14.10 system scales both CPU cores 1400-3400 MHz on a sub-second resolution. I believe that it is scaling down too quickly, as when I am running multiple heavy applications the CPU cores stay pegged for quite a long time.

How can I set up the system to scale the CPU frequency **up** when it hits 80%, but only to scale **down** after the load stays below 30% for more than one second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can d it by selecting `conservative` governor and setting its sampling time. Here are [instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling) on how to do it. Please note that on modern Intel CPUs new driver is used, that calls `conservative` governor a "`powersave`" one.